# Getting "VM Exception while executing eth_call: invalid opcode"

Tags: solidity

I have a very basic contract to test out some functionality, but when I call the functions getContractAddress() and getThrowaway(), I get the invalid opcode error. I'm using truffle and testrpc, and I get the error after running some commands in truffle console (below).

Here is the full contract in question:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

import "./MetaCoin.sol";

contract Guess {

// Constructor, gives this contract 10k coins
function Guess(){
    MetaCoin metaCoin = new MetaCoin(); //I think this should give the contract 10k coins
}

function getContractAddress() constant returns (address){
    return this;
}

function getThrowaway() constant returns (string){
    return "Hello";
}


}
```

And here are the commands I'm running in truffle console.

```
guess = Guess.deployed();
guess.then(function(instance){return instance.getThrowaway.call();})
```

Same problem when I run getContractAddress().

Here is the full repo for reference: https://github.com/willikers19/GuessTheEth

When I run commands in a similar fashion from this contract (https://github.com/willikers19/ethereum-demo-tools/blob/master/GeektSolidity/contracts/Geekt.sol), they succeed so it feels like I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: After restarting my computer and picking this up again the next day, I found that the answer from Rob Hitchens worked! I then tried my inputs again to see what I was doing wrong and I found that my inputs worked too... I think the issue stems from not restarting testrpc between truffle migrations.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as you (with a similar set up). Just testing throwaway calls I get `invalid opcode`. However if i shut down my testrpc and start it back up and migrate my contract fresh the calls all work. Why would this be happening? Does `truffle migrate` still need to be confirmed by the network?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var guess;
Guess.deployed()
.then(function(instance) {
  guess = instance;
  return guess.getContractAddress.call()
})
.then(function(response) {
  console.log("Response:", response);
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: After restarting my computer and picking this back up the next morning, I find that your solution works, but when I tried my console inputs again, so did mine... So I guess the real fix was to restart my computer. Thanks for your (somewhat indirect) help!

Comment: Not working for me, make truffle crash with the same error "VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
"

Comment: var MillionMoneyInstance;
    MillionMoney.deployed()
    .then(function(instance) {
      MillionMoneyInstance = instance;
      return MillionMoneyInstance.ownerWallet.call()
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log("Response:", response);
    });

Comment: You should post that as a new question with details about what you did before and during the test. The original poster was on a certain step but your situation is less clear.

Answer (score 0):

You not only need to run:

```
truffle migrate
```

But before you do it, you need to edit the migration script in which you specify which contracts migrate to the blockchain. [Check here](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop#migration).

Cheers